Where to store sensitive configuration files?
What is the best practice for storing configuration files containing "sensitive" data (passwords, API Keys etc., connection string)?
For instance in my git repo, in which there lives a dockerized application, I check in a file containing the docker run command to start the application in a local/dev environment:
docker run \
-d \
--publish 12345:7000 \
--env MySecret="MyDevSecret" \

When deploying to a production server I must execute a similar command, only with the production secrets instead:
docker run \
-d \
--publish 12345:7000 \
--env MySecret="MyProductionSecret" \

What is the "best practice" location to store such a file? I see the following options:

check this file into a git repo separate from the project.
check this file into a git repo separate from the project, but encrypted. This shifts the questions to "where do i store my encryption keys"
store the files locally, requiring some backup infrastructure
store the files in some cloud service

